# Frattini Argument Application

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup of a $G$ where $N$ is normal in $G$ and $p \not| |N|$. Then we can conclude (I have shown by use of a Frattini argument)

$$N_{G/N}\left(QN/N\right) = N_G(Q)N/N$$

To show this we notice that $Q \in Syl_p(QN)$.

I want to now show

$$C_{G/N}(QN/N) = C_Q(Q)N/N$$

I tried the argument used for the first equality but it just leads to showing that some element of $C_{G/N}(QN/N)$ is a member of $N_{G/N}(QN/N)$ which is obvious. I think we want to use the fact that from the first equality we know $C_{G/N}(QN/N)$ is normal in $N_G(Q)N/N$ and try and use an element of the latter to conjugate (act on) the former but I am a little lost so a little push/guidance would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose as above and let $xN \in C_{G/N}(QN/N)$. Then, we know $x \in N_g(Q)N$. That is, $x=yn$ for $y \in N_G(Q)$ and $n \in N$. Let $qN \in QN/N$

$$qN=(qN)^x=(qN)^y \implies q^{-1}y^{-1}qy \in N$$

However, $y \in N_G(Q)$ gives $y^{-1}qy \in Y$ and so $q^{-1}y^{-1}qy \in N \cap Q=1$ since $N$ is $p'$. Therefore, $[q,y]=1$ and so $y \in C_G(Q)$. That is, $x \in C_G(Q)N$ giving the result.